# how to install opcache on debian with php 5.4.4?

Tags: debian, pecl, opcache

I am running a Debain PHP5.4.4 and I want to install opcache.

I tried with :

```
    pecl install opcache
    pecl install ZendOpache-beta
```

Not good: "No releases available for package "

(Since server is in production I don't think it would be safe to install php5.5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pecl install zendopcache-7.0.5` source: https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache
Don't forget activate it by adding extension to php.ini